# Does Server and Database location needs to be in the same region for efficiency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a social network website where user are able to upload their content. 80% user is in Malaysia and 15% in USA. Should I place the server in Taiwan (middle between USA & Malaysia) or Singapore (closer)? GCP don’t have Database in Singapore, so should I place the server in SG and DB in Taiwan?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer to your question may vary. In your case since most users are in a specific region that is where the server should go. The amount of hops and bandwidth available to your users will make the difference in milliseconds or even a second but it will be faster - usually.

The time it may vary is the actual infrastructure in the country or place where the server farm is. However since you are dealing with AWS or Google I doubt you have anything to worry about.

So if your customers in the majority come from X region it makes sense to use servers as close to that region as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer twg. The problem is that the closest server doesn't have DB in the area, so with this setup, the DB will have to be on different area. Will it affect performance? If so, shouldn't I just get the 2nd closest area where it also have DB in there too?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ary realize you are talking milliseconds here...if the setup is correct. I honestly do not think you have anything to worry about. We all deal with remote servers. And i assume you are on AWS. Google, Azure, AWS are all safe in those areas